# Why unity do not include my shader to build but log them?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, shader

I have shader which i use in scene and they work in editor but unity do not want build them on some reason. Sems like unity do not see that i have used this shaders, but why in editor all works fine?
It's happend when i install another unity version.
[added image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RQ8F.png)

Comment: Have you added the shader(s) to the Always-included list in the graphics settings of your project?

Comment: yep, it's does't help no way

Comment: is there any chance that the shader is not compatible with the target platform? (webgl for example is terrible for it)

Comment: idk, it's happen when i change unity to more new version, super simple shader for android which worked before